# How do I use the result of a method in a boolean? (In Java)

Tags: java, methods, boolean

I'm trying to understand how I can use the result of my method `calculateBMI()` in a boolean.

Here's my method with the return value that I need

```
public int calculateBMI(){
        return (100*100*weight)/(length*length);
    }
```

Here's what I've tried so far but I'm a big noob to Java and I know it is wrong, can someone elaborate on how I can use the return value of the `calculateBMI()` in a boolean for a return value? Sorry if this is very beginner Java.

```
public boolean hasOverweight(){
    if (calculcateBMI() >= 30) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
```

EDIT: Solved, thanks guys! Appreciated :)

Comment: The usage seems just fine to me. What makes you think it is wrong?

Comment: `return calculcateBMI() >= 30;`? The fact that call a method here doesn't matter. If you can figure out `return (100*100*weight)/(length*length);`, you should be able to figure out this.

Comment: @VaibhavKarani When I call for `calculateBMI()` in the boolean, IntelliJ tells me it cannot resolve the method in my current class; but I need the result of that method in order to have a true or false value. How do I go about this? I'm very new to Java

Comment: Well, what class do you define the method in?  What class do you try to use it in?

Comment: @raymono are both the methods in the same class?

Answer (score -1):

What you have is perfectly fine. You get a `int` and compare it to a known value. A slightly shorter statement would be

```
    public boolean hasOverweight(){
        return (calculcateBMI() >= 30);
    }
```

Both are equivalent, and have no real performance difference.

Answer (score -1):

I´m not sure if i undernstood your question , but you can do this :

```
public boolean hasOverweight(){
   return calculcateBMI() >= 30
}
```

Just with that validation return true o false